# Get option name from a listview in android studio

Tags: java, android

I can't seem to find a clear answer anywhere, but I was wondering how to extract a name of a list option when you click it, so I can store it into a variable in the next screen. I've no idea how to start it other than a findByView

Comment: If the name is in your `ListView`, then it's in your dataset. Get it from there, rather than trying to go roundabout through `View`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    final ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    list.setClickable(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    // use position to find item from your data array
    //For example List<String> names;
    //names.get(position)
      }
    });
```

Comment: Im not too sure what your doing here. Whats with the clickable and clicklistener. Since im on a different XML file from where I made the list, I cant use the Adapterview (or it would let me at least, it just says its an unused import statement).

Comment: @ToddHoward123 can you please share your code? It doesn't matter if the view is inflated from XML. If it is contained by the activity then you can find that listview and add the item select listener.